# Macro for highlighted cells rather than specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an excel macro that will grab information that is highlighted in one excel workbook and paste it into a new workbook.

The code I currently have takes the info from specific cells, but I need it to be of certain cells that are highlighted throughout the spreadsheet.

The code I currently have is

```
Sub copy()

Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Master Data").Range("A8:I14").copy _
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")


End Sub
```

EDIT

By highlighted, I do not mean highlighted with a colour or with formatting. I mean by selecting a multitude of cells by click and dragging to select cells

Comment: How the cell is highlighted? Using conditional format or any other way?

Comment: The cells are just text and numbers. Some of the columns are green in colour but there is no formatting.

Comment: You want to copy the current active selection from one workbook to another? How do you want them pasted? Exactly where they were? Into a contiguous block based on the current selection in the destination sheet? More specific info will get you a better answer more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySpecificRange()

    Dim srcRange As Range
    Set srcRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A8:I14")

    Dim myCell  As Range
    Dim srcRangeColored As Range

    For Each myCell In srcRange
        If myCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            If Not srcRangeColored Is Nothing Then
                Set srcRangeColored = Union(srcRangeColored, myCell)
            Else
                Set srcRangeColored = myCell
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

    If Not srcRangeColored Is Nothing Then
        srcRangeColored.copy Worksheets(2).Range("A2")
    End If

End Sub
```

Concerning that you want only cells, colored in vbYellow the code above works. Just make sure that you fix correctly the `Worksheets(2)` and `Worksheets(1)` as you wish.

Depending on what you want, probably it is a better idea to save the colored values in a data structure (array or list), and to put it one after another in range `A2`. Thus, consider that you are interested in the yellow cells of  `A1:D10` range only:

[image]

Thus, trying to get this:

[image]

You may use the `myColl` as a `Collection` and add any `vbYellow` cell to it. Then, using the incremented `cnt`, it is easy to put the values of the collection on a single row:

```
Sub CopySpecificRange()

    Dim srcRange As Range
    Set srcRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:D10")

    Dim myCell  As Range
    Dim srcRangeColored As Range
    Dim myColl As New Collection

    For Each myCell In srcRange
        If myCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            myColl.Add myCell.Value2
        End If
    Next myCell

    Dim cnt As Long: cnt = 1
    With Worksheets(2)
        For Each myCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, myColl.Count))
            myCell = myColl.Item(cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next myCell
    End With

End Sub
```

---

And concerning the edit, where highlighted means selected.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

```
Sub CopySelectedRanges()

    Dim myCell  As Range
    Dim srcRangeColored As Range
    Dim myColl As New Collection

    For Each myCell In Selection.Cells
        myColl.Add myCell.Value2
    Next myCell

    Dim cnt As Long: cnt = 1
    With Worksheets(2)
        For Each myCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, myColl.Count))
            myCell = myColl.Item(cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next myCell
    End With

End Sub
```